# Batch update on Exchange WebDav

Tags: exchange-server, webdav

I am trying to update a bunch of items in a shared Exchange calendar, using WebDav.

What I want to do is rename events, similar to what I would do in SQL:

```
UPDATE appointments SET subject = 'New Name' WHERE subject = 'Old Name'
```

Is there a way to do this in a WebDav query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [BPROPPATCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142735(EXCHG.65).aspx) method for this